# Use multiple text formats in same Excel cell using openxlsx

Tags: r, openxlsx

Is it possible to use openxlsx to format different parts of the text in a single cell in different ways? In the same way that in Excel itself you can highlight text in the formula bar and (for example) underline a single word?

[image: Screenshot of Excel worksheet with two cells containing the text: "when typing into Excel manually it's possible to format parts of a single cell differently" and "Is this possible using openxlsx?", respectively]

For context, I am automating the production of an Excel template that previously has been made by hand. I am keen for it to look as similar to the previous template as possible, so users won't notice there has been any change to its production. There are a series of instructions above a table which use a fancy bullet point in Wingdings font, but the rest of the cell is in Arial.

Comment: Not possible as far as I know. Your best bet would be a combination of R and VBA or entirely relying on VBA.

Comment: I do not think this is possible in the current package: https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/46

Comment: Thanks both :) I'd looked for duplicate questions before I posted, but hadn't found this one!

Comment: Have a look at [`fmt_txt()`](https://janmarvin.github.io/openxlsx2/reference/fmt_txt.html) in openxlsx2